# Copying multiple s3 objects at once without --recursive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a list of s3 object that I want to copy from one bucket to another. This is the scenario:

| Object int Bucket 1 | Object in Bucket 2 |
| --- | --- |
| s3:/bucket1/path/to/object1 | s3:/bucket2/different/path/{date}/{mode}/object1 |
| s3:/bucket1/path/to/object2 | s3:/bucket2/different/path/{date}/{mode}/object2 |
| s3:/bucket1/path/to/object3 | s3:/bucket2/different/path/{date}/{mode}/object3 |

I can not use the option `--recursive` as I'm changing completely the objects keys. I'm executing one `aws s3 cp` per file and it's pretty slow. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: then use `aws s3 sync` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't `aws s3 cp s3://bucket1/path/to/ s3://bucket2/different/path/{date}/{mode}/ --recursive` do what you're after?

Comment: No because every file has a different {date} and {mode}. But thinking it better I could group them by {date} and {mode}. I think I will do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run 3x that command in parallel on your computer by adding a `&` at the end of the command:

```bash
aws s3 cp s3:/bucket1/path/to/object1 s3:/bucket2/different/path/{date}/{mode}/object1 &
aws s3 cp s3:/bucket1/path/to/object2 s3:/bucket2/different/path/{date}/{mode}/object2 &
aws s3 cp s3:/bucket1/path/to/object3 s3:/bucket2/different/path/{date}/{mode}/object3 &
```

This will run the commands 'in the background' and at the same time rather than one-at-a-time. The messages on your screen will be a bit overlapping and confusing, but it will work.